# Encrypt (cryptojs) - Decrypt (erlang)

Tags: encryption, erlang, cryptojs, kdf

I have a value encrypted with cryptoJS (AES) and need to decrypt using Erlang crypto library. The problem for me lies in the fact that to be able to decrypt in Erlang using `aes_cbc_128_decrypt(Key, IVec, Cipher)` I presume, I will need to know what the IVec is that was used and how the Key should be made up.

```
var ciphertext = Crypt.AES.encrypt("message here", "4445");  
// U2FsdGVkX1+ZxppJRvcbdWJW1xAxSlm2akm7ZFnY9GU=
```

Comment: You would have to implement the [`EVP_BytesToKey`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html) and derive the key and IV from the password and the salt that is included in the ciphertext (decoded bytes 8-15 (0-indexed)). I found [this](https://github.com/Yongke/shadowsocks-erlang/commit/933a5bb383267ba29c8378fb5d66d29f9434c173#diff-71261a4477a27c06012918360a54332cR121), but it looks wrong.

Answer (score 0):

IVec = <<0:128>>, and the length of the key should be a multiple of 16.